# Windows 8.1 sleep even if it is disabled

Tags: windows-8.1, sleep

I just upgraded W8 to W8.1. When power is connected I got auto sleep disabled. Whenever I manualy put computer to sleep then after wake up it keep sleeping in like 3 minutes.

It doesn't matter what is set in power options windows. It fall asleep in the short period if there is set never or ten hours.

I remember that I got this problem with windows 8 and after weeks of googling I found a solution where I needed to change something in registry. Do anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: change the samething in the registry it was likely reverted when you installed the update.

Comment: I would really like to but I've lost the thread so I don't know what is the "something".

Comment: Could this be a screeen saver set to "blank"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the original thread.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/windows-8-pro-goes-to-sleep-after-60-seconds-of/b1a32492-f9cc-4db9-ad70-987af074fa08

In short, when you wake computer with external keyboard for example, windows may guess its remote wake up and fall a sleep in much shorter interval.

According to posted link just delete `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\238C9FA8-0AAD-41ED-83F4-97BE242C8F20\7bc4a2f9-d8fc-4469-b07b-33eb785aaca0\DefaultPowerSchemeValues`

Comment: Didn't work for me, even after restart.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your time for  Hard Disk "turn off" - this option you found in advance Power Settings.

Comment: I adjusted HDD turn off time to 200minutes and it seems not falling to sleep. It doesn't make any sense to me :/

Comment: Mayby you have problem with ACPI drivers for your notebook? Please  chek a new drivers other fix for you notebook.